# Hash each line in Text file Python MD5

Tags: python, hash, file-io, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to write a program which will open a text file and give me an md5 hash for each line of text. For example I have a text file with:

```
66090001081992
66109801042010
68340016052015
68450001062015
79450001062016
```

This is my code:

```
import hashlib
hasher = hashlib.md5()
archivo_empleados = open("empleados.txt","rb")
lista = (archivo_empleados.readlines())



archivo_empleados.close()
```

Comment: What is your problem: How to hash a bytes sequence or how to loop through the lines of the file or something else?

Comment: how to loop through the lines

Comment: Be sure to read the tutorial on [input and output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). Section 7.2.1. Methods of File Objects shows how to iterate over lines of a textfile in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the file with a `with` context manager(don't need to call `.close()`), then iterate each line of the file with a `for` loop and print the MD5 hash string. You also need to encode in `utf-8` before hashing.

```
import hashlib

def compute_MD5_hash(string, encoding='utf-8'):
    md5_hasher = hashlib.md5()
    md5_hasher.update(string.encode(encoding))
    return md5_hasher.hexdigest()

with open("path/to/file") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(compute_MD5_hash(line))
```

Which gives hash strings like the following:

```
58d3ab1af1afd247a90b046d4fefa330
6dea9449f52e07bae45a9c1ed6a03bbc
9e2d8de8f8b3df8a7078b8dc12bb3e35
20819f8084927f700bd58cb8108aabcd
620596810c149a5bc86762d2e1924074
```

You can have a look at the various `hashlib` functions in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update).